# Trying to call a function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a java script file called Toolbar.js in which I am trying to call a function that is in my App.js file as the following:

```
<DrawerToggleButton click={props.drawerClickHandler}/>
```

The above does not work, it shows "Unresolved variable drawerClickHandler" which I assume means that Toolbar.js can not see the functions in App.js. I have tried this without using props with no results. How can I get this to work?

Also just want to state the program will build and run with no errors, just that the button I am trying to map the function to, does nothing when I click it.

Code below:

Toolbar.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Toolbar.css';
import  DrawerToggleButton from '../SideDrawer/DrawerToggleButton'
import '../SideDrawer/DrawerToggleButton';
import sideDrawer from "../SideDrawer/SideDrawer";

const toolbar = props =>(
    <header className="toolbar">
        <nav className="toolbar_navigation">
            <div>
                <DrawerToggleButton click={props.drawerClickHandler}/>
            </div>
            <div className="toolbar_logo"><a href="/dashboard">Kleen Portal</a></div>
            <div className="spacer" />
            <div className="toolbar_navigation-items">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
);

export default toolbar;
```

App.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
// import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Routes from "./Routes";
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
// import { Navbar } from "react-bootstrap";
import  Toolbar from './components/Toolbar/Toolbar';
import SideDrawer from './components/SideDrawer/SideDrawer';
import Backdrop from './components/Backdrop/Backdrop';


function App(props) {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const [isAuthenticating, setIsAuthenticating] = useState(true);
  const [sideDrawerOpen, setIsSideDrawerOpen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    onLoad();
  }, [isAuthenticating, isAuthenticated]);

  async function onLoad() {
    try {
      await Auth.currentSession();
      setIsAuthenticated(true);
      props.history.push("/dashboard");
    }
    catch(e) {
        alert(e);
    }
    setIsAuthenticating(false);
  }

  function handleLogout() {
    setIsAuthenticated(false);
    props.history.push("/login");
  }

  function drawerToggleClickHandler(){
    setIsSideDrawerOpen(!sideDrawerOpen)
  }

  let sideDrawer;
  let backdrop;
  let toolBar;

  if(isAuthenticated){
    toolBar = (
        <Toolbar
            handleLogout={handleLogout}
            drawerClickHandler ={drawerToggleClickHandler}
        />
    )
  }

  if (isAuthenticated && sideDrawerOpen){
    sideDrawer = <SideDrawer/>;
    backdrop = <Backdrop/>
  }
  return (
    <div className="App container" style={{height: '100%'}}>
      {toolBar}
      {sideDrawer}
      {backdrop}
      {/*<Toolbar/>*/}
      {/*<SideDrawer/>*/}
      {/*<Backdrop/>*/}
      <Routes appProps={{ isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated }} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

DrawerToggleButton.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './DrawerToggleButton.css'

const drawerToggleButton = props => (
    <button className="toggle-button" onClick={props.click}>
        <div className="toggle-button_line" />
        <div className="toggle-button_line" />
        <div className="toggle-button_line" />
    </button>
);

export default drawerToggleButton;
```

Comment: Can you add the code for `DrawerToggleButton`, is it passing the `click` prop to appropriate DOM element?

Comment: @Zink inside DrawerToggleButton  how are you accessing? can you show more code for understanding

Comment: Added extra code as requested

Comment: can you check you browser console, is there any error ?

Comment: can you show the error you are getting ?

Comment: @Zink Looks like its getting called. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cteko5?file=index.js

Comment: The reason your function is not working is because you have a call to set `authenticated` to `false` right outside of your `try {} catch(e) {}` block. So your `authenticated` value is always going to be `false`. Thus, your check of `authenticated && sideDrawerOpen` will also always be false.

Comment: @Jimmay Outside of the try{} catch{e} block is setIsAuthenticating(false), inside try{} is setIsAuthenticated(true);. My main issue is when I type the code <DrawerToggleButton click={props.drawerClickHandler}/> in Toolbar.js, it says that drawerClickHandler does not exist.

Comment: So you say it _shows "Unresolved variable drawerClickHandler"_ and right after it, that the _program will build and run with no errors_. Which one is true?

Comment: So it builds and runs but there is a green squiggly line under _drawerClickHandler_ which signifies that its not a code breaking issue but clicking the button does nothing. When hover the mouse over _drawerClickHandler_ "Unresolved variable drawerClickHandler" is displayed